# Can't link between folders in express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm pretty new to node.js and express.js so I feel I may be having problems with the syntax, I have the following node.js code:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();

app.set('port', process.env.PORT);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'static')));
app.get('/', function(req,res){
   res.render("/public/index")
});
app.get('/secure', function(req,res){
  res.render("/secure/index")
});
var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  var port = server.address().port;

});
```

This allows me to access the secure page perfectly fine, however the page throws an "Internal Server Error" whenever trying to access the public page, why is this? My file structure is

```
static
-public
--index.html
-secure
--index.html
```

If I move the public index.html up into static then it works fine, however I'd prefer to have the above file structure, is there anyway I can do this? Thanks.

Comment: I suspect it's looking at the root of your drive for the templates. Try e.g. `./public/index` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you make a request at `yourdomain:yourport/`, express will handle the request in `app.get("/", ..)` and found the handler is `res.render`. So it will return an error since this function requires a [view engine](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.render) to be defined on top of `app.get()`.

Since the files served are static html files, you can remove the `app.get()` middleware. You already have the [static handling middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'static')));`

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();

app.set('port', process.env.PORT);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'static')));

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  var port = server.address().port;
});
```

So to get the `public` page, just make a request at `yourdomain:yourport/public`. Meanwhile the secure page is available at `yourdomain:yourport/secure`.

Answer (score 0):

I had to go with:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'static')));

app.get('/', function(req,res){
   res.render("public/index")
});
```

to get this working with your directory structure.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried that exact syntax but it's still throwing the same error?

Comment: What version of Express do you have, and what is the exact URL you are loading?

In my case my `PORT` is 8877, so I'm loading: `http://localhost:8877/` and this gives me the page in static/public/

Comment: 4.13.4, the URL loaded is given through cloud foundry https://test-nodejs-app.run.aws-usw02-pr.ice.predix.io/

Comment: You should be getting a stack trace. Have you set `NODE_ENV` to `production`? This disables stack traces.

Comment: I haven't, my app.js is                                                                             var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();

app.set('port', process.env.PORT);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'static')));
app.get('/', function(req,res){
  res.render("public/index")
});
app.get('/secure', function(req,res){
  res.render("/secure/index")
});
var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  var port = server.address().port;

});

Comment: It might be set up by cloudfoundry. Are you using `cf push` to upload new versions? If so can you post the log?

Comment: Yes, the log for pushing is several pages long, is there anything I should be looking out for?

Comment: I've never used cloudfoundry but I found a sample log, look for "Creating runtime environment" and  "NODE_ENV=production".

Comment: Yes that is in the log

Comment: OK well that explains why Express is not producing stack traces. As for how you turn it off properly I'm not sure. Try: `process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development';` at the top of your file as a workaround.